# Problems using Remote Desktop between Win7 desktop and Win8 laptop

Tags: windows-7, networking, windows-8, remote-desktop, credentials

I'm trying to connect to my desktop from my laptop through Remote Desktop. I've gotten as far as enabling it in system settings (Allow connections from computer running any version of Remote Desktop), but whenever I try to connect with my laptop, it displays my desktop's account, but even though I put in the right password it just keeps saying "the logon attempt failed". So I tried to add my laptop as a user in the Select Users dialogue, but I can't select my laptop as a location, so I can't connect my account (they're on the same LAN network). So I tried making a homegroup and put them both in it, but my laptop still didn't show up as a location. I even disabled Windows Firewall. If anybody has any suggestions, please help. Also, my desktop doesn't have a wireless card, it's connected by ethernet. Hopefully that helps.

Answer (score 1):

For the username field, try typing COMPUTERNAME\username

COMPUTERNAME being the name of the target computer and username being the account on the target computer.

Doing this will force Remote Desktop to search for a user account on the target system.

Comment: Nothing. Still searching my local computer.